# Json изменение каждого y

Tags: python, json

При помощи python и библиотеки json, я должен поменять каждый position y в коде

```
{
  "map": "FlatGrass",
  "props": [
    {
      "name": "Container1",
      "uniqueId": 61.12375,
      "position": {
        "x": 0.806536257,
        "y": 0.5050001,
        "z": 7.76004028
      },
      "rotation": {
        "x": -2.83643042E-09,
        "y": 0.9998909,
        "z": -1.01446735E-08,
        "w": 0.0147708561
      },
      "isKinematic": true,
      "instantiationData": null,
      "runtimeData": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Container1",
      "uniqueId": 141.458038,
      "position": {
        "x": 8.790194,
        "y": 0.5050002,
        "z": 7.99596834
      },
      "rotation": {
        "x": -2.83643042E-09,
        "y": 0.9998909,
        "z": -1.01446735E-08,
        "w": 0.0147708561
      },
      "isKinematic": true,
      "instantiationData": null,
      "runtimeData": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Container1",
      "uniqueId": 349.381256,
      "position": {
        "x": 16.7738514,
        "y": 0.505000234,
        "z": 8.231896
      },
      "rotation": {
        "x": -2.83643042E-09,
        "y": 0.9998909,
        "z": -1.01446735E-08,
        "w": 0.0147708561
      },
      "isKinematic": true,
      "instantiationData": null,
      "runtimeData": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Загрузить данные JSON из файла - `with open("file.json", "r") as file:
\n    data = json.load(file)
`. перебирать каждый элемент в списке - `for prop in data["props"]:`. увеличиваем значение y поля позиции на 1 `prop["position"]["y"] += 1`. 80% уже есть. дальше попробуйте сами